# How do you merge consecutive repeating elements in an array?

Tags: ruby

I need to merge consecutive repeating elements in an array, such that

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 1]
```

becomes

```
[1, 2, 3, 1]
```

`#uniq` doesn't work for this purpose. Why? Because `#uniq` will produce this:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: why doesnt uniq work? are you using uniq or uniq!?

Comment: See also the duplicate question _[Eliminate consecutive duplicates of list elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5544701/405017)_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def remove_consecutive_duplicates(xs)
  [xs.first] + xs.each_cons(2).select do |x,y|
    x != y
  end.map(&:last)
end

remove_consecutive_duplicates([1, 2, 2, 3, 1])
#=> [1,2,3,1]
```

This returns a new array like `uniq` does and works in `O(n)` time.

Comment: Did not know of *each_cons*, nice one!

Answer (score 11):

There is a abstraction in the core that pretty much does the job, [Enumerable#chunk](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
xs = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1]
xs.chunk { |x| x }.map(&:first)
#=> [1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Far shorter, cleaner and more efficient than the accepted answer.

Comment: This will not work correctly if the array has nil values though, as it will cause these values to be discarded.

Comment: Good point. I had no idea `chunk` had these special values. If the input can have those special values, they all should be wrapped.

Answer (score 3):

sepp2k's answer is already accepted, but here are some alternatives:

```
# Because I love me some monkeypatching
class Array
  def remove_consecutive_duplicates_2
    # Because no solution is complete without inject
    inject([]){ |r,o| r << o unless r.last==o; r }
  end

  def remove_consecutive_duplicates_3
    # O(2n)
    map.with_index{ |o,i| o if i==0 || self[i-1]!=o }.compact
  end

  def remove_consecutive_duplicates_4
    # Truly O(n)
    result = []
    last   = nil
    each do |o|
      result << o unless last==o
      last = o
    end
    result
  end
end
```

And although performance is *not* everything, here are some benchmarks:

```
Rehearsal --------------------------------------------
sepp2k     2.740000   0.010000   2.750000 (  2.734665)
Phrogz_2   1.410000   0.000000   1.410000 (  1.420978)
Phrogz_3   1.520000   0.020000   1.540000 (  1.533197)
Phrogz_4   1.000000   0.000000   1.000000 (  0.997460)
----------------------------------- total: 6.700000sec

               user     system      total        real
sepp2k     2.780000   0.000000   2.780000 (  2.782354)
Phrogz_2   1.450000   0.000000   1.450000 (  1.440868)
Phrogz_3   1.530000   0.020000   1.550000 (  1.539190)
Phrogz_4   1.020000   0.000000   1.020000 (  1.025331)
```

*Benchmarks run on removing duplicates from `orig = (0..1000).map{ rand(5) }` 10,000 times.*

Answer (score -3):

does `!uniq` not work for what you are doing?

http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_array.html

Comment: -1 1.) he SAID in his answer that it doesn't work and 2.) its uniq! not !uniq

Comment: `!uniq` is not a valid method name in ruby. `uniq!` does the same thing as `uniq`, but in-place. So it's not what the OP wants (since he only wants to remove *consecutive* duplicates).

Comment: Didnt notice the "consecutive" duplicate requirement. OP might want to explicity state that.

Comment: I just added this clarification. Thanks.