# Eliminate consecutive duplicates of list elements

Tags: ruby

What is the best solution to eliminate consecutive duplicates of list elements?

```
list = compress(['a','a','a','a','b','c','c','a','a','d','e','e','e','e']).
p list # => # ['a','b','c','a','d','e']
```

I have this one:

```
def compress(list)
  list.map.with_index do |element, index| 
    element unless element.equal? list[index+1]
  end.compact
end
```

Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: As you have a working answer, what are your criteria for 'best'? Fastest? Shortest? Most readable to a new user? Least memory? Trickiest?

Comment: Note that this is **not** a duplicate of _["Remove from the Array Elements that are Repeated"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444269/remove-from-the-array-elements-that-are-repeated)_ (but it is similar enough to include a link here).

Comment: @fl00r, it's ruby 1.9.2. @Phrogoz, ok, fastest i guess.

Comment: @Phrogz yes, instead it is a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576652/how-do-you-merge-consecutive-repeating-elements-in-an-array
And the accepted answer is a duplicate of that http://stackoverflow.com/a/8105422/227755

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Nice opportunity to use [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk), as long as your list doesn't contain `nil`:

```
list.chunk(&:itself).map(&:first)
```

For Ruby older than 2.2.x, you can [`require "backports/2.2.0/kernel/itself"`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) or use `{|x| x}` instead of `(&:itself)`.

For Ruby older than 1.9.2, you can [`require "backports/1.9.2/enumerable/chunk"`](http://github.com/marcandre/backports) to get a pure Ruby version of it.

Comment: One day I willy get off my lazy ass and write an REP for `Identity = ->x { x }` to be included in the core library.

Comment: @Jörg: or `Object#self`? One could then write `&:self`. In neither case do we gain much typing, though...

Comment: @JörgWMittag: For `self`/`identity`/?, see https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6373

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune: the same can be achieved using `itself` as `list.chunk(&:itself).map(&:first)`

Comment: @potashin Not back in 2011!

Answer (score 6):

Do this (provided that each element is a single character)

```
list.join.squeeze.split('')
```

Answer (score 5):

Ruby 1.9+

```
list.select.with_index{|e,i| e != list[i+1]}
```

with respect to @sawa, who told me about `with_index` :)

As @Marc-André Lafortune noticed if there is `nil` at the end of your list it won't work for you. We can fix it with this ugly structure

```
list.select.with_index{|e,i| i < (list.size-1) and e != list[i+1]}
```

Comment: You're using it! (by array you mean list.) Nice idea.

Comment: You see that this case fits perfect my old question. It would be nice to use itarator this way: `list.select{ |item| item != item.next }`

Comment: @fl00r For your previous question, I see, it's nice. (By the way, list.size --> list.size - 1, or maybe you want to use `<` instead?) Your answer is still straightforward enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Requires Ruby 1.8.7+ due to Object#tap
def compress(items)
  last = nil
  [].tap do |result|
    items.each{ |o| result << o unless last==o; last=o }
  end
end
list = compress(%w[ a a a a b c c a a d e e e e ])
p list
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "a", "d", "e"]
```

Comment: This is the only answer I could get to work with an array of hashes

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ['a','a','a','a','b','c','c','a','a','d','e','e','e','e']

enum = arr.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a", "a", "d",
  #                  "e", "e", "e", "e"]:each>
a = []
loop do
  n = enum.next
  a << n unless n == enum.peek
end
a #=> ["a", "b", "c", "a", "d"]
```

[Enumerator#peek](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) raises a `StopIteration` exception when it has already returned the last element of the enumerator. [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles that exception by breaking out of the loop.

See [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-each) and  [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next).  [Kernel#to_enum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-to_enum)<sup>1</sup> can be used in place of `Array#each`.

<sup>1 `to_enum` is an `Object` instance method that is defined in the `Kernel` module but documented in the `Object` class. Got that?</sup>