# Reduce stacks of duplicates in an array into only one of them in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, distinct

I'll take it directly:
For example I have an array

```
int[] integers = {1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2};
```

And all I like is to reduce all the stacks of 2 into only one 2. I need to get this at the end:

```
{1, 2, 4, 5, 2};
```

I read about the .Distinct() method and every kind of comparers, but that method deletes all the same elements and I don't want this. I still think there shold be some certain method to do it via Linq or somethig. Thanks!

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350641/array-remove-duplicate-elements

Comment: If I understand you, what you want is something that does the same thing as [the Unix ``uniq`` utility](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq), except that it acts on the entries of an array rather than on the lines of a file.

Comment: What language are you using? There seem to be "unique" functions in many languages, but they eliminate _all_ duplicates, not just consecutive ones. Here is what someone had to do to work around this in Ruby, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576652/how-do-you-merge-consecutive-repeating-elements-in-an-array

Comment: @David K thanks, I'm gonna check that Ruby out, I think I'm gonna be ok with that. Gonna post a refference as soon as I'm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LINQ, Luke!

```
var result = integers.Where((n, i) =>
    i == 0 ? true : n != integers[i - 1]);
```

More concise:

```
var result = integers.Where((n, i) =>
    i == 0 || n != integers[i - 1]);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think .net doesn't have function for this.

So you should use simple foreach.

```
var result = List<int>();
foreach(var item in integers)
{
    if(!result.Any())
    {
        result.Add(item);
    }
    else if(result[result.Count() - 1] != item)
    {
        result.Add(item);
    }
}
```